# MySQL: get max row in each group when max value is not unique

Tags: mysql

There are many questions out there close to this, but I can't find one with a solid example of how to do quite what I want. I need to get a single max row for each group when the maximum value is not unique within a group. Here's a table:

```
| id | source | name | message_time |
|----|--------|------|--------------|
| 1  | a      | cool | 2020-08-18   |
| 2  | a      | cool | 2020-08-18   |
| 3  | a      | neat | 2020-08-02   |
| 4  | b      | nice | 2020-08-19   |
| 5  | b      | wow  | 2020-08-17   |
```

For each `source`, I need a single full row associated with the maximum `message_time`. Since the max message time is not unique within a group, both of these are valid outputs:

```
| id | source | name | message_time |
|----|--------|------|--------------|
| 1  | a      | cool | 2020-08-18   |
| 4  | b      | nice | 2020-08-19   |
```

```
| id | source | name | message_time |
|----|--------|------|--------------|
| 2  | a      | cool | 2020-08-18   |
| 4  | b      | nice | 2020-08-19   |
```

When there are multiple candidates for max, I just want to randomly select a single row. How can I achieve this with a mysql query?

I'm using MySQL 5.7

**Edit:**

So I messed around some more and realized this works:

```
SELECT table.*
FROM (
  SELECT source FROM table
  GROUP BY source
) groups
LEFT JOIN table
ON id = (
  SELECT id FROM table
  WHERE source = groups.source
  ORDER BY message_time desc
  LIMIT 1
);
```

I think I even understand why it works, but I don't know what no good, very bad practices I am doing here. Also, can it be simplified?

Comment: The fact that there are two valid outcomes is a bit of a headache. I think you should decide which of those you want, and why.

Comment: And state which version of MySQL you're using

Comment: You have to define which value for `id` you want to return. randomly selecting one is a bad idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the setup I must deal with. Tweaking the data to make this work somehow is possible, but I'm not sure what to do exactly to make it make sense. On insert, I could potentially increment the milliseconds of each duplicate message time, but that feels pretty icky. Open to suggestions.

Comment: Why do you not (simply?) select the `MIN` value for `id` (or the `MAX`)?

Comment: @Luuk I actually need the id (and name) to be legitimately from one of the actual max rows. Returning id = 3 would be possilbe if I did that, but this is not valid, since its not an id of one of the rows with the max message_time.

Comment: "And state which version of MySQL you're using"

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you use the row_number window function, which requires mysql 8.0 or mariadb 10.2 or better.

```
select id, source, name, message_time
from (
    select id, source, name, message_time,
        row_number() over (partition by source order by message_time desc, rand()) as row_num
    from a_table
) a_table_with_row_numbers
where row_num=1;
```

On earlier versions, you can do this:

```
select
    0+substr(max(concat(prefix,id)),19) id,
    substr(max(concat(prefix,source)),19) source,
    substr(max(concat(prefix,name)),19) name,
    max(message_time)
from (
    select id, source, name, message_time, concat(message_time, lpad(1e8*rand(),8,'0')) prefix
    from a_table
) a_table_with_sortable_prefix_string
group by source;
```

Comment: saw that mysql 5.7 was added to the question and added a way to do it there

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT
  MAX(m.id) as id,
  x.source,
  x.message_time
FROM
  (SELECT
    source,
    MAX(message_time) AS message_time
  FROM
    source
  GROUP BY 
    source ) x
INNER JOIN source m ON m.source=x.source AND m.message_time=x.message_time
GROUP BY
  x.source,
  x.message_time;
```

This will select the source and the max(message_time),

and then select the max(id) for that source and message_time

EDIT: some typo's in the query, and a test added:

sampledata created using:

```
CREATE TABLE source (id INTEGER, source CHAR(1), name VARCHAR(10), message_time DATE);
INSERT INTO source VALUES
   (1,'a','cool','2020-08-18'),
   (2,'a','cool','2020-08-18'),
   (3,'a','neat','2020-08-02'),
   (4,'b','nice','2020-08-19'),
   (5,'b','wow','2020-08-17');
```

output of query:

```
+------+--------+--------------+
| id   | source | message_time |
+------+--------+--------------+
|    2 | a      | 2020-08-18   |
|    4 | b      | 2020-08-19   |
+------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: Pretty sure this would give me the id 3 for source a, which is incorrect

Comment: pretty sure that you did not test this, let me correct the missing ',' in the query, and correct the invalid alias near the inner join. After that is will add the output.

Comment: ah, yes it does give me one of the correct ids, but now you can't select the name column. It's not actually selecting the whole row. group by at the top level like this is not really an option.

Comment: For every column, that is not in the `GROUP BY`  YOU should decide which value you want to be returned by your sql-statement. It is NEVER a `SELECT *` or a `select whole row`.

Comment: re-read your own question ("get max row in each group when max value is not unique")

Comment: When I used the word "group", I wasn't explicitly referring mysql's GROUP BY clause, but rather the logical grouping I am interested in. Then when I said "get max *row* ..." and gave examples of the desired output with all the fields in the entire row, I figured it was clear enough what I wanted. Let me know if there is a way I can tweak the question so this is more easily understood.

Comment: The problem is when asking a question tagged `mysql`, and then talking about "grouping" and "max" makes it easy to confuse these terms with their SQL versions `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`.   (no need to change your question)